# Anchor links pointing to external site issue in Outlook

Tags: html, internet-explorer, outlook

My issue is very straightforward: I am generating a newsletter from a webpage that I design in HTML. I would like to create anchor links to connect a summary section to different parts of the newsletter.

I have tried the following

```
<a href='#part1'>Click here for part 1</a> [etc...]
<a name='part1'>Part 1</a>
```

The problem is that when the HTML page is generated it replaces `#part1` with `www.mypagename/test.html#part1`, providing a reference to the external page. I would like my links to anchor to the outlook email and not the external page (just `#part1`!!).

How can I achieve this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround also